# Excel: If Dropdown value = "Yes", retrieve the following data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am currently having the following problem. I created a dropdown menu with the values "Yes" and "No" in Sheet1. My goal is to show certain data in sheet2, only if the dropdown value in sheet1 displays a "Yes". Currently I only retrieve a 0.

My current code in sheet2 (which does not work):

```
=IF('Sheet1'!$M2="Yes"; 'Sheet2'!A2;0)
```

Any suggestions?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you get the dropdown menu from data validation?

Comment: Yes I did indeed.

Comment: I'm not having any issues with it, are you sure the data for the validation doesn't have leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: An additional space was identified by excel which did not show in first case. It works now, thank you for the help!